# How do I correctly launch a shell environment with node-pty in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, electron, node-pty

I have an Electron App that's using node-pty to create a pseudo-terminal instance. This instance is created as follows:

```js
const pty = require('node-pty');
const os = require('os');
const shell = process.env[os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'COMSPEC' : 'SHELL'];
const ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: 100,
  rows: 40,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env
});
```

When I launch the app from the vscode terminal using (`electron .`) everything works as expected. I.e. the shell can find all programs just like it would in cmd.exe or Terminal.app.

However, if I build the app, and open it via double clicking on it, I notice that my path does not contain certain directories such as `/usr/local/bin/`, which can cause certain programs (like `brew`) to fail with "Not found" errors.

Notably, if I launch the electron app from a terminal on mac using `open -a MyElectronApp` everything works as expected.

I suspect my app needs to initialize the path differently somehow. However, since this is a cross-platform app, I'd like to avoid doing anything like "if os.platform == 'darwin' load /etc/paths".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information. I assume my issue is probably due to a misunderstanding/ignorance of shell environments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced same issue. Used https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path

process.env.PATH was not available for the electron process in production mode. The above `fix-path` fixes the issue

Comment: Thanks Edwin, I completely forgot about this post, but yes this fixed it for me too!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is a bit deeper than just PATH, and "fix-path" is just a band-aid.

To illustrate the problem, let's say you're using [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), which is the default on macOS. Zsh uses several startup files, the most notable of which are:

- **.zprofile**, which is run for *login* shells
- **.zshrc**, which is run for *interactive* shells

Where this can trip you up is that your PATH may be being set in .zprofile.

This is normally not a problem when you launch a shell in a terminal, because macOS Terminal.app runs it as a login shell.

But when you are just invoking /bin/zsh with pty.spawn, you're only creating an interactive shell. That means .zshrc will get sourced, but .zprofile won't.

To make node-pty launch zsh as a login shell, you have two options:

1. You can pass the "--login" flag, *if your shell supports it*. Zsh and Bash both do. This is [what Visual Studio Code does](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1c0c4726d30a0574739b35cc6d7a7dea9b3decb2/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalProfileResolverService.ts#L247).
2. You can set argv[0] to the name of the shell prefixed by a hyphen, e.g. "-zsh". This effectively tells the spawned process that its name is "-zsh" instead of "/bin/zsh" or similar, and—most crucially—is the accepted and most universal way on Unix systems to indicate the shell should be a login shell.

The latter option is not yet supported in node-pty releases as of this writing, but I submitted [a PR](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty/pull/627) adding this support which is tagged for review for a future version.

I am [using my patched version](https://github.com/mattieb/webterm/blob/c1927b36e9a58223d3464779d5901936a9cf34c4/pty/package.json#L16) in a personal project:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-pty": "github:mattieb/node-pty#add-argv0-support"
  }
}
```

This makes a new option, "argv0", available, [to which you can set](https://github.com/mattieb/webterm/blob/c1927b36e9a58223d3464779d5901936a9cf34c4/app/src/main/shell-config.ts#L8) a hyphen followed by the base name of your shell:

```js
import { basename } from "node:path";
import { spawn } from "node-pty";

const file = process.env.SHELL ?? "/bin/sh";
const argv0 = `-${basename(file)}`;
const pty = spawn("/bin/zsh", [], { argv0 });
```

With both strategies, you simply don't need to pass "process.env" as the environment to spawn. Instead, the shell's own startup will set the environment.